# Want to convert DataBufferUShort to DataBufferInt

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

I have a `BufferedImage` of type `BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY` (`DataBufferUShort`) which I want to convert to `BufferedImage` of type `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB (DataBufferInt)`. Any suggestions how can I achieve it ?

Comment: Did you tried it ? What exception you are getting ?

Comment: Well, thing is, my actual image is 16 bit but when I get the image to my client layer, its in DataBufferUShort form. Now I have negative values for all the values above 15bits in my short array extracted from DataBufferUShort. I have to find minimum pixel value, maximum pixel value, pixel mean withing selected region etc. I don't have much expertise in this area. I am still trying out different things but that does not look like what I am trying.

Comment: Please have a look this http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=java.awt.image.DataBufferUShort may it will help you

Comment: Do you want to convert the image, or just extract min/max/mean? If you just need the unsigned values, just mask out the sign like `int unsignedVal = shortVal & 0xFFFF`. If converting, do you want to keep the 16 bit/pixel, or is it okay to go *down to 8 bit/pixel*, as you would do when converting to `TYPE_INT_RGB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to extract the min/max/mean, there's no need to convert the `BufferedImage`:

```
// Assuming image is always TYPE_USHORT_GRAY
short[] values = ((DataBufferUShort) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
double mean;

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    int unsignedValue = values[i] & 0xFFFF;

    if (unsignedValue < min) {
        min = unsignedValue;
    }
    if (unsignedValue > max) {
        max = unsignedValue;
    }
    // ...etc. for mean and other values you like to extract. :-)
}
```

If you want to convert the image to `TYPE_INT_RGB` for display purposes (without caring about precision) you can simply create a new image of the desired type and paint the original over it:

```
BufferedImage display = new BufferedImage(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g = display.createGraphics();
try {
    g.drawImage(original, 0, 0, null);
}
finally {
    g.dispose();
}
```

Comment: You hit the target. This is exactly what I am suggesting my second party here. To keep this clear to you, I get the Buffered Image from one system in UShort form, need to do some processing and display the same on an user interface owned by second party software. When I set the image to them as UShort type, they don't have the anding with 16bit value even though they have check if image is UShort, which is why I get negative values sometimes for min values. I was just looking If I could get hold of straight away convesion from UShort to int type Buffered Image.We are on same page I guess :)

Comment: @DilDil Sounds to me like you should talk to the third party provider and have them fix their software. Although the values are technically signed (as are all Java's integral types), the `DataBufferUShort` should treat all values as unsigned, that is what it is for. Is the third party software Java or other language? Maybe there is a type mapping problem?

Comment: They are also using Java. I am starting discussion with my second party software (not third party, so it should be easy for us) to improve their code as you rightly mentioned. Final display viewport is owned by them and since its medical Image, we wont be able to compromise on the Image quality I suppose. For my knowledge same I will definitely check your last proposal.

Comment: Conversion from TYPE_USHORT_GRAY to TYPE_INT_RGB that you suggested, works well but that leads to unexpected min, max values from second party software. So will proceed with suggesting them changing their algorithm for Ushort and send us right values. Thanks guys for all your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, a BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY (DataBufferUShort) is indeed an encoding of each pixel on 16 bits (2 bytes). But a BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB (DataBufferInt) if an encoding of a pixel with 3 colors on a single int! Consequently, if you do it, you are going to loose the 16 bits precision and fall to 8 bits. If you still want to do it, you can use the getRaster().getSample and getRaster().setSample.

In order to do what you want, you have to create a BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM, with a single channel and DataBufferInt. Here is a code to do it.

```
ColorSpace myColorSpace = new FloatCS(channel == 1 ? ColorSpace.TYPE_GRAY : ColorSpace.TYPE_RGB, channel) ;
int[] bits = new int[channel] ;
Arrays.fill(bits, 32) ;
ColorModel myColorModel = new ComponentColorModel(myColorSpace,bits,false,false,ColorModel.OPAQUE,DataBuffer.TYPE_INT) ;
return new BufferedImage(myColorModel, myColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(width, height), false, null) ;
```

[EDIT]Here are more precisions.

FloatCS just extends ColorSpace:

```
public class FloatCS extends ColorSpace
{
private ColorSpace rgb = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB) ;

public FloatCS(int type, int channel)
    {
    super(type, channel) ;
    }

public float[] fromCIEXYZ(float[] pixel)
    {
    return fromRGB(rgb.fromCIEXYZ(pixel)) ;
    }

public float[] fromRGB(float[] RGB)
    {   
    return RGB ;
    }

public float[] toCIEXYZ(float[] pixel)
    {
    return rgb.toCIEXYZ(toRGB(pixel)) ;
    }

public float[] toRGB(float[] nRGB)
    {
    return nRGB ;
    }
}
```

and then you perform a simple copy:

```
BufferedImage imshort = new BufferedImage(512, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY) ;
BufferedImage imint = ImageNew.Integer(imshort.getWidth(), imshort.getHeight(), 1) ; // It calls the first little code I gave you to create a BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM with DataBufferInt
short[] bufshort = ((DataBufferUShort)imshort.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;
int[] bufint = ((DataBufferInt)imint.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;
for (int i=0 ; i < bufshort.length ; i++)
    bugint[i] = bufshort[i] & 0xFFFF ;
```

Comment: My JDK doesn't have a `FloatCS` class. I think you want to use `ColorSpace.getInstance(...)`. But you are not really gaining anything by doing this... The `BufferedImage` is just a blank image. You still have to covert all the values.

Comment: Yes you are right, FloatCS just extends ColorSpace! And yes again, this code creates the new BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM with a DataBufferInt. Then it's a simple copy (I've edited my message)!